# What's the reason why Django has SmallIntegerField?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm wonder why it's provided. The field is database dependent, doesn't that make it totally unreliable to use?

I want to store birth year in a model, kinda like

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  born = models.IntegerField()
```

Of course this requires very little space, it should always be 4 "characters" long, so a PositiveSmallIntegerField would maybe fit, but why should I choose it instead of normal IntegerField?

Comment: 4 character years? Y10K problem?

Comment: Like if ever something I write will actually make it to year 10,000...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Performance on many RDBMs can be heavily dependent on row size. While a "purist" approach might say that the application should be completely independent of the underlying data structure, over many rows improvements like using a smaller integer could shave gigabytes off table size, which makes more of the table fit in memory, which drastically improves performance.

I would use a small integer like this for say, a primary key on a table that would always have <100 rows, especially when this is stored as a foreign key in a table I expect to grow very large. While the size is implementation defined, it's safe to assume that it is greater than 127 at the very least.

Comment: SmallIntegerField is also handy when you have a fixed number of options, and are using the choices parameter. For example:

    born = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=((1, '1960-1969'), 2, '1970 - 1970))

Comment: I don't know, I would never use a small integer field on a primary key. If your ID auto-increments and rows are being removed and added, it just takes one ridiculous person to recreate enough rows over a few years to cause a problem. IDs are the one thing I'd say are not a good fit for such optimizations.

Comment: Unfortunately the link to that ABCs optimization posts is now dead. I have tried but couldn't find a similar reference; I'd never heard of it and I'm interested. Does anyone have more information?

Answer (score 18):

> The field is database dependent, doesn't that make it totally unreliable to use?

It's not *totally* unreliable.  SMALLINT is part of the SQL standard and certainly MySQL and PostgreSQL both have small integer types that go from -32768 to +32767

Answer (score 11):

This is one of those things that is the way it is because it got that way.

Django supports SmallIntegerField because Django grew up on PostgreSQL, and PostgreSQL supports smallint. The PosgreSQL docs say

> The smallint type is generally only used if disk space is at a premium.

While it seems kind of quaint now, when 1TB disks can be had at the corner store, it wasn't all that long ago when disks were a lot smaller, costing significantly more per byte. Memory, too. Using a smallint (where appropriate) in an index means fitting more row indexes into RAM cache, which meant better performance.

Comment: I would also add that using `SmallIntegerField` would _slightly_ reduce the chance of typos. If you know the value of your integer will be below 32,768 or above -32,767 you won't be able to save a larger or smaller integer by accident.

Answer (score 3):

You would choose SmallIntegerField if you wanted to save space in the database.  The limit on the value is database-dependent, but that doesn't make it unreliable.  It just means you have to know what database system you are using, and find out what the limit is for that system.

Comment: Well, wouldn't to make it unreliable in the sense that you can't count on switching the backend DB to not break things?

Comment: I don't count that as unreliable.  That's portability.  As engineers, we have to analyze problems and tools, then combine the tools in a way that solves the problems.  If your problem allows you to only use databases that support SmallIntegerField, and space in the database is a potential issue, then SmallIntegerField is a great solution with no unreliability.

Answer (score -3):

Year *is* date without taking care of months and days. Choose the [`DateField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField) and hence enjoy all the power Django provides to you. Since you store born yeas, this also allows you in the future to simply accept months and days.

Comment: Because I don't want a date, I want a year. And that is not a good fit with a DateField.

Comment: @Velmont: I think year *is* date.

Comment: No, a date has month and day as well.

Comment: I don't do that because it is hard to use date objects as years. It is also *wrong*. Because I would effectively have to put a date and month in there (because it is not possible without), HENCE that makes it 100% wrong. In the beginning I started with DateTime, but found out that it was not a smart move in the end.

Comment: @Gabor: You are partly right, a date could be a partial date. But as in almost every system, date is assumed to have a month and a day, and you cannot have just the year set, so it cannot be partial. With no partial date support, storing it as an integer is bloody the way to go... (Similarly, you would store age as integer, not as a timespan)