# Django: How to use float precision instead of double precision in MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, orm

`models.FloatField` creates a double in MySQL.
Is it possible, and how, to create a float precision field instead of double precision?

The [justification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516610/whats-the-reason-why-django-has-smallintegerfield) is similar to that of having SmallIntegerField.

Comment: I don't see why you'd want to do this.  What's it buying you?  Disk space is cheap.

Comment: @duffymo - In my case I have tens of float columns, and millions of entries, so moving from double to float could significantly shrink the db size + enhance query efficiency

Comment: Still trivial.  "tens" of float columns?  "millions" of entries?  I doubt that it'll have the effect you're imagining.  Where's the data to say that this is so?  It's a micro-optimization that won't be worth the cost.  Large databases are terabytes in size.  Unless yours is, I'd say that you should do something more productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options to do this, but I don't understand why you would want to.

1. Change it in the database, won't work when recreating the tables but Django won't do a manual cast so if the database changes, so do the results.
2. Create a custom fieldtype (i.e. inherit `FloatField` and change `get_internal_type()` so it returns something like `SinglePrecisionFloatField`. After that you will also need to create your own database backend and add your custom type to `creation.DatabaseCreation.data_types` (source: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/backends/mysql/creation.py)
3. Change every `FloatField` to single precision. Like above you would have to create your own database backend and/or change the `FloatField` implementation in the current one.

Comment: In my case I have tens of float columns, and millions of entries, so moving from double to float could significantly shrink the db size + enhance query efficiency

Comment: @Jonathan: It won't make much difference in performance (if any at all). And in terms of space requirements, assuming you've got 1 million entries than it will save you roughly 4 megabytes ;)

Answer (score 5):

Well there is a better way than that and a much easier one. I also wanted the same thing with my db, when I came across the following db_type() method in django.

First, you need to create a custom Field in django by inheriting the Field class

```
class customFloatField(models.Field): 
    def db_type(self,connection):
        return 'float'
```

then you could use this as any other model field in your model class

```
number = customFloatField(null=True,blank=True)
```

I tried and this does work for me in MySQL. To change it as per the connection type, you would have to check the connection setting in an if statement and change accordingly.

More about this is mentioned in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/